# How to call api from Ruby on rails app once in a month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, cron, haml

I am a newbie to Ruby on rails.... I need advice on how to achieve the below task:

Task: Call api and get JSON data which should be processed for header/footer.haml files.
      There are api calls for 2 different languages.

concerns: api's should be called only once in a month.

Currently I am doing this:
application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :get_header

require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'httparty'

def get_header
  header_api_response = HTTParty.get('api')
  @res = JSON.parse(header_api_response.body)
end
```

then I process @res in header.haml file  to get the data. But I need this api call function to be called once in a month only. Should I create a cron job outside rails to call this api??
Whats the best solution?

Comment: create a rake task for it and then use the `whenever` gem to schedule a cronjob that executes that rake task (https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: You could also use [Clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating cron will be the best solution for your situation. You may create a cron for that and for using the cron there is a very good and easy to implement gem is available called [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

And [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby?view=asciicast) is a simple tutorial on how to implement that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.. I have few concerns here: 1) when api call fails to give the proper response 2) when user can choose languages like English/Arabic, where can I put the logic which api-response to refer to.... any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are making a dynamic header you should be storing the header in the DB. Refer to the gem documentation of the whenever gem first to clearly understand how it works. Language preferences must be stored in the DB as well so on behalf of user preference you may call the specific API by reading the preferred language from DB.